# 400 (Bad Request Vue Js, axios and Django rest framework for POST and PUT Method

Tags: django, vue.js, axios

[image]

My Get and Delete Request is working perfectly. But, getting 400 Bad request while POST or PUT method are calling. And for your kind information my Django rest framework is working fine in POST-MAN and in my local http://127.0.0.1:8000/doctor. And I am including my local machine picture too. [image] [image]

This is working fine. In my Axios code:

```js
data(){
    return{
        doctors:[],
        modalTitle:"",
        DoctorName:"",
        DoctorId:0,
        DoctorNameFilter:"",
        DoctorIdFilter:"",
        doctorsWithoutFilter:[]
    }
},
methods:{
    refreshData(){
        axios.get(variables.API_URL+"doctor/")
        .then((response)=>{
            this.doctors=response.data;
            this.doctorsWithoutFilter=response.data;
        });
    },
    addClick(){
        this.modalTitle="Add Doctor";
        this.DoctorId=0;
        this.DoctorName="";
    },
    editClick(doc){
        this.modalTitle="Edit Doctor";
        this.DoctorId=doc.id;
        this.DoctorName=doc.name;
    },
    createClick(){
        axios.post(variables.API_URL+"doctor/",Qs.stringify({

            data:this.DoctorName
        }))
        .then((response)=>{
            this.refreshData();
            alert(response.data);
        });
    },
    updateClick(){
        axios.put(variables.API_URL+"doctor/"+this.DoctorId, Qs.stringify({

            data:this.DoctorName
        }))
        .then((response)=>{
            this.refreshData();
            alert(response.data);
        });
    },
    deleteClick(id){
        if(!confirm("Are you sure?")){
            return;
        }
        axios.delete(variables.API_URL+"doctor/"+id)
        .then((response)=>{
            this.refreshData();
            alert(response.data);
        });

    },
    FilterFn(){
        var DoctorIdFilter=this.DoctorIdFilter;
        var DoctorNameFilter=this.DoctorNameFilter;

        this.doctors=this.doctorsWithoutFilter.filter(
            function(el){
                return el.DoctorId.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                    DoctorIdFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                )&&
                el.DoctorName.toString().toLowerCase().includes(
                    DoctorNameFilter.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                )
            });
    },
    sortResult(prop,asc){
        this.doctors=this.doctorsWithoutFilter.sort(function(a,b){
            if(asc){
                return (a[prop]>b[prop])?1:((a[prop]<b[prop])?-1:0);
            }
            else{
                return (b[prop]>a[prop])?1:((b[prop]<a[prop])?-1:0);
            }
        })
    }

},
mounted:function(){
    this.refreshData();
}

}
```

My Django settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for DrAppointment project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-s6!#d2y#rlptr&#e)+0e^=m=n(&!zrqa$byd#pwbgzpogvo8qe'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'appointment',
    'rest_framework',

    'corsheaders',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DrAppointment.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DrAppointment.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# REST_FRAMEWORK Settings
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

In my view.py :

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import Doctors, Appointment
from .serializers import DoctorsSerializer, AppointmentSerializer
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, generics
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.decorators import APIView


# from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
class DoctorList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Doctors.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DoctorsSerializer


@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
class DoctorDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Doctors.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DoctorsSerializer
```

In My urls.py:

```
    from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from appointment import views
# from .views import DoctorList, DoctorDetails
# from .views import doctor_list, doctor_details, appointment_list, appointment_details

urlpatterns = [
    path('doctor/', views.DoctorList.as_view()),
    path('doctor/<int:pk>', views.DoctorDetails.as_view()),
    # path('appointment/', AppointmentList.as_view()),
    # path('appointment/<int:pk>', AppointmentDetails.as_view()),

]
```

Comment: You need is to debug network request in devtools. There you can clearly see what's sent to the server and how it differs from successful POSt. What you show in console is just a symptom.

Comment: Ok, Sir, I am check it out and let you know.